# Extract Objective-C class information from library at runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos

I was wondering if there were a way to extract information from an objective-c app, static or dynamic library and/or framework?

Information such as an array of class names without instantiating or running the target.

I've checked google and the apple developer documentation and haven't found anything.

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F-script appears to be able to do what you want, but I'm no expert.  Check out www.fscript.org.

Comment: Thanks John. This may be more appealing than the lower level class dump, at least F-script has a framework to embed in the application although I haven't researched enough to conclude what I need is available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract classes from an application/dynamic library, there is a handy tool called [ClassDump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/).

It can even generate the header files in order to get an overview of the classes, protocols, etc.

If you want to do it at runtime, then take a look at the source code to learn how to load and parse the different mach-o segments.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. I will also send out a prayer to the god of frameworks to encourage authors to put the core of this functionality into something runtime reusable!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent starting point for reverse-engineering Cocoa apps:

http://culater.net/wiki/moin.cgi/CocoaReverseEngineering

It mentions F-Script, class-dump, and a few others.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm almost at the point of implementing what I need so this is a great reference/overview to keep by my side when developing.